# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression in react when using div

Tags: reactjs

What is the problem here? May be for div?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';

class Home extends Component {
    state = {

    }

    render() {
        return
        (
            <div>
                Home
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Home;
```

> Error is: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzknN.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please post your code as text

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings Looks like there's no code too.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake ! Updated with code

Comment: Bring the opening brackets on same line as return

Comment: Thanks ! It works but I used return like this in react native. Found no problem there ! Why this happens in react?

Comment: This is not just React, it's [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-automatic-semicolon-insertion/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/3773011)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what's happening:

```
class Home extends Component {
    state = {

    }

    render() {
        return // Here you are returning and the function stops executing... as suggested in the comment bring up the ( on the same line as return...
        (
            <div>
                Home
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your response

Answer (score -1):

Your file is saved as `Home.js`, so the compiler doesn't understand some of the syntax. Try saving as `Home.jsx`.

Comment: But the tutorial I am following is written like this also saving as .js

Comment: Ok, try @Boy With Silver Wings suggestion to bring brackets on the same line as return.